# Why doesn't this RegEx match the phone number? How to fix?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this phone number: +44 (0) 1234 123456

which the following regex is attempting to validate, but fails:

`var regexPhone = new Regex(@"^(\+)?([0-9\s\-])*$");`

Can somebody tell me why it's failing? Is it possible to change this so that it will validate the number above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not allow any brackets.

See if Jabos's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013782/regular-expression-for-phone-number) can help you along.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are called parentheses.

Comment: outside the US it's fairly common to refer to 'parentheses' as 'brackets'

Comment: @juharr: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/round-brackets  I am from Germany where UK english is taught at schools.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) to debug your regex.

Answer (score 0):

As Jens pointed out, your regex does not allow brackets.

```
^(\+)((\([0-9\s\-]*\))|([0-9\s\-]))*$
```

This regex should work. It allows some digits to be inside brackets also.